# How do I select a specific enum value based on it's position within the enum definition in lua?

Tags: enums, lua

## Background

In lua, my team has established a function that define enums as such:

```
Enumeration = enum{
    'SOME',
    'VALUE' }
```

The details of the enum function are here:

```
function enum( names )
    local t={}
    local __enumID = 0
    for _,k in ipairs(names) do
            t[k]=__enumID
            __enumID = __enumID+1
    end
    reutrn t
end
```

## Issue

I have a nested for loop where the outer loop is looping based on the number of enumerations in Enumeration, and the inner loop is looping on a different condition with a member that is assigned a value based on the enum as seen below:

```
for i = 1,2 do
    for j = 1,101 do
        someCollection['outerArray_['..i..'].innerBooleanArray_['..j..']'] = true
        someCollection['outerArray_['..i..'].innerEnumArray_['..j..']'] = Enumeration<i> <-- Where I want to access the enumeration numerically
    end
end
```

Normally you can select the specific value of an enum like this: `Enumeration.SOME` but I was wondering...

## Question

Is there a way to select SOME using it's integer value, i.e. something like `Enumeration.<0>`?

Comment: It depends on how did you define the function `enum`.  This is not a standard Lua function.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I have added how my team has defined enums in lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to the loop in `enum`:

```
t[__enumID]=k
```